# Grails - Domain object doesn't validate correctly

Tags: validation, grails, domain-object

I'm trying to set the date of birth of a person using jQuery Datepicker. However, all I get is that the `Property dateOfBirth must be a valid Date`.

So, originally, my controller looks like this:

```
def update(Person personInstance) {
    if (personInstance == null) {
        // do Something
        return
    }

    if (personInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond personInstance.errors, view: 'edit'
        return
    }

    // do the rest
}
```

I figured out, that with jQuery I should use a `SimpleDateFormat` object in order to generate a proper `Date` object. Nevertheless, even if I directly assign a new `Date` object to `dateOfBirth` and subsequently validating the `personInstance` domain object - like in the following code segment - I still get the `Property dateOfBirth must be a valid Date` error.

```
def update(Person personInstance) {
    if (personInstance == null) {
        // do Something
        return
    }

    // added code
    personInstance.dateOfBirth = new Date()
    personInstance.validate()
    // added code

    if (personInstance.hasErrors()) {
        respond personInstance.errors, view: 'edit'
        return
    }

    // do the rest
}
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: The reason why you are still seeing errors is because validation is automatically called after binding your command/domain object. Use `personInstance.clearErrors()` before calling `personInstance.validate()` manually. You can see more about this in the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/clearErrors.html

Comment: Should I add that as an answer?

Comment: You can also use the @BindingFormat annotation above the field to bind the date in the format its received from the client side.
More on this here:
http://grails.org/doc/2.4.x/api/org/grails/databinding/BindingFormat.html

Comment: Thank you @NikhilBhandari. Works equally well and even saves me some lines of code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are still seeing errors is because validation is automatically called after binding your command/domain object when the method is called.

Use `personInstance.clearErrors()` before calling `personInstance.validate()` manually to clear out any existing binding/validation errors. You can see more about this in the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/clearErrors.html).